# Given an element $\omega \in H^{(1,1)}(X,\mathbb{C})$ how to construct a line bundle with chern class $\omega$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, characteristic-classes, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a Kahler complex variety of dimension $1$. Let $\omega\in H^{(1,1)}_{dR}(X,\mathbb{C})$ such that $\int_{X}\omega = 0$. Can we find a line bundle $L$ over $X$ such that $c_1(L) = \omega$? If the answer is affirmative, how can we do it?.

Comment: Hint 1: Chern classes are integral. Hint 2: Lefschetz' theorem on $(1,1)$-classes.

Comment: Curiously this is precisely what geometric quantization does.